# ClamAV continous scan

Tags: linux, anti-virus, clamav

I want ClamAV to continuously scan some folder in my computer; i was thinking something like extremely low priority scan of all files (background scan), and some high priority scan over created/modified file intercepted with inotify.

Do you think this is a good idea? how would you implement this?

The idea of the low scan is to scan all the system to prevent virus to sneak in; the inotify hook is  to check heavily used folder like Download and folder synchronized with other host.

problem is, how can i manage the priority of the different scan that are probably running in parallel?

Comment: "Do you think this is a good idea?" - Just get a program that provide active protection instead of passive.

Comment: What would you use? Remember that I got some folder that get file shared by my colleagues

Comment: You never mentioned that; my suggestion doesn't change though .

Comment: I said folder synchronized with other host. Anyway what would you use?

Comment: I don't even know what OS your are using.  With that said, I won't provide a software recomendatio, there are many choices where a security software continuously scans any file added to the system.

Comment: My bad system is Linux and I have no clue, so at least a couple of suggestion would be welcome